# WPF Binding to a function return

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

I have a "Checked ListBox", a `ListBox` with a `CheckBox` for each of my Items.
In this `ListBox` I have a List of Players.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyPlayers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" Margin="69,51,347.4,161.8">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ???}" Content="{Binding Path=Pseudo}" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    SavingContext MyDatabaseContext;
    public ObservableCollection<Player> MyPlayers
    {
        get
        {
            return MyDatabaseContext.MyPlayers.Local;
        }
    }

    Tournament _MyTournament;
    public Tournament MyTournament
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyTournament;
        }

        set
        {
            _MyTournament = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(Tournament myTournament)
    {
        MyDatabaseContext = new SavingContext();
        MyDatabaseContext.MyPlayers.Load();
        MyTournament = myTournament;
    }
}
```

I pass in my `ViewModel` a `Tournament`, that contains an `HashSet` of `Players` called `Participants`.
I would like to bind my `IsChecked` properties to the result of `MyTournament.Participants.Contains(this)` with this being the `Player` related to the `CheckBox`. But I can't manage to make it works.

Edit :
I tried to use a Converter, but with no success.
`<helper:PlayerToTournamentRegistered x:Key="PlayerToTournamentRegistered" />`

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlayerToTournamentRegistered}}" Content="{Binding Path=Pseudo}" />
</ListBoxItem>

public class PlayerToTournamentRegistered : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Temp test to see if it would work
        if (value == null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I get an error each time `Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception`
Any Advices ?

Comment: It is impossible to provide any advice without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried and what's not working. Data binding requirements are simple: public properties supported by property change notifications. A converter must work without throwing exceptions, and converter inputs still must have property change notifications, so WPF knows when to run the converter. If that doesn't get you back on track, please fix your question so it includes the needed information.

Comment: I don't know what would be missing to have a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, appart for the MVVM implementation that is classic, and the entity framework structure (that I detail). You can litterally add the rest in a new project to have the same reproducible example.

Comment: _"I don't know what would be missing to have a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example"_ -- then you haven't read the [mcve] page. See also the articles linked at the bottom of the [ask] page (and of course, make sure you read that too). As for what's missing, you didn't even bother to include the `Tournament` or `Player` classes, never mind provide a code example that is both **complete** and **minimal**.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, the only important matter is that my Tournament contains a HashSet of Players, that *minimal*, the player class doesn't matter, (as long as it contains a field pseudo if you are really reproducing the entire project), I left it out to keep the code minimal. I still don't see why it would not be reproducible, I won't put all the basic and useless information as it would disturb ppl from the main problem. Yes I could explain how I use entity framework, but that would be of absolutly NO use to help me solve my problem.

Comment: _"Sorry to disagree"_ -- you seem to be under the impression that you are the person who gets to judge whether your question is of sufficient quality. Further, you clearly have not bothered to read and/or understand the resources available to you, which will guide you regarding what _is_ a question of sufficient quality, because you can't tell the difference between one that is, and yours. Good luck with that. You will continue to get poor or no response if you refuse to provide good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it working using a MultiConverter.
The first error that I had was due to the fact that the Mode is by Default Two Way, I only want to have my Converter work OneWay.
I used a MultiBinding to send to my Converter both my ListBoxItem and my Tournament.
My Converter return true or false, and is linked to my CheckBox.IsChecked properties.

List Box :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyPlayers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" Margin="69,51,347.4,161.8">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Pseudo}" >
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PlayerToTournamentRegistered}" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.MyTournament"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Converter :

```
public class PlayerToTournamentRegistered : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(values[0] is Student) || !(values[1] is Tournament))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Tournament myTournament = (Tournament)values[1];
        Student myPlayer = (Student)values[0];
        if (myTournament.Participants.Contains(myPlayer))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```